# Product of arbitrary Mersenne numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let be $p$ and $q$ two arbitrary Mersenne numbers.

> Is there a simple proof that $p\cdot q-1$ can never been a square?

$p\cdot q-1$ can instead be a 3rd power for:

$p=3,q=3$

$p=7,q=31$

$p=63,q=127$

In these cases it is interesting to see that $p\cdot q+1$ is an even semi-prime, as in the case $3\cdot 3 +1=10$ or $7\cdot 31+1=218$ or $63\cdot 127 +1=4001\cdot 2$

Comment: By "power of 3" I think you mean "3rd power".

Comment: yes surely it is so 3rd power

Comment: but it is hopeless to find another 3rd power

Comment: @Garry Myerson anything to do the 3rd powers with a sequence https://oeis.org/A002897

Comment: If it's hopeless to find another 3rd power, then it can't have much to do with that infinite sequence, can it?

Comment: @Gerry Meyerson $7\cdot 31 +4$ has $17=4^2+1$ as greatest prime factor, $63\cdot 127+4$ has $1601=40^2+1$ as greatest prime factor.

Answer (score 4):

Write $p=2^m-1$ and $q=2^n-1$ where $m>n$ without loss of generality. If $pq-1=(2^m-2^{m-n}-1)2^n$ is a square, then so is $2^m-2^{m-n}-1$. But then $m=n+1$, as $m\ge n+2$ implies $2^m-2^{m-n}-1\equiv 3\pmod 4$. Now, $2^m-2^{m-n}-1=2^m-3$, which clearly is not a square if $m$ is even, and which is not a square if $m$ is odd either as in this case $2^m-3\equiv (-1)^m\equiv -1\pmod 3$.

Comment: Aren't you missing a factor of $2$? $n$ is going to be an _odd_ number, so it's $2(2^m+2^{m-n}-1)$ that's a square.

Comment: Not quite _necessarily_ odd -- we could on the face of it have n=2. But in every other case n is odd.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: No, I am not missing anything. The numbers $2^m-2^{m-n}-1$ and $2^n$ are coprime; if the product of two co-prime numbers is a square, then so is each of them.

Comment: D'oh! Of course they are. You're quite right. Sorry.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the case $m$ even. $2^n$ must also be a square, forcing $n$ to be even, yielding that $m=n+1$ is odd, and thus, $2^m-3\equiv -1\pmod{3}$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(2^m-1)(2^n-1)-1=2^{m+n}-2^m-2^n$ is a square. Obviously we can't have $m=n$, so the largest power of 2 dividing this is $2^{\min(m,n)}$. If neither of our Mersenne primes is 3, then that exponent is an odd number, which can't possibly be the largest power of 2 dividing a *square*.

So one of our primes, say $2^m-1$, is 3 and we have $2^{n+2}-2^n-4$ where $n$ is an odd prime. This is 4 times $2^n-2^{n-2}-1$. Unless $n=3$ this is $-1$ mod 4 and therefore can't be a square.

So the only remaining case to check is $m=2,n=3$ yielding $3\cdot7-1=20$ which happens not to be a square.

Comment: You're doing Mersenne *primes*, where OP only says Mersenne *numbers*.

Comment: Yikes! I confess I didn't even notice that OP didn't just mean Mersenne primes, but since they use 63 as an example it's clear that they didn't. (I don't think I've heard "Mersenne number" used to mean "power of 2 minus 1" before.)